# Error when trying to perform repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

Consider this data frame:

```
> pdf
# A tibble: 80 × 9
   Subject SessionType Group ErrsOfCom ErrsOfOm TotalErrors   Acc AvgRT
   <fct>   <fct>       <fct>     <int>    <int>       <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 17      BL          HC            0        7           7 0.912  70.7
 2 17      SWD         HC            0       12          12 0.85   49.5
 3 18      BL          MDD           0       13          13 0.838  45.6
 4 18      SWD         MDD           0       12          12 0.85   49.1
 5 19      BL          MDD           2        9          11 0.862  60.7
 6 19      SWD         MDD           4        7          11 0.862  72.3
 7 20      BL          MDD           0       13          13 0.838  45.4
 8 20      SWD         MDD           0        8           8 0.9    69.3
 9 21      BL          MDD           3       12          15 0.812  51.3
10 21      SWD         MDD           0       10          10 0.875  62.9
# ℹ 70 more rows
```

Each `Subject` has exactly two observations (one per Session Type). I am interested in the effects of `SessionType` and `Group` on `Acc`. It is important to note that `Acc` is a proportion with very low variance. It has no NA values.

I thought to use `rstatix` to perform a repeated measures ANOVA. Here's the code I tried:

```
x <- anova_test(
           data = pdf,
           dv = Acc,
           wid = Subject,
           within = c(SessionType, Group)
)
```

However, I get

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

At first I thought this may have been due to the low variance of `Acc`, but trying the same test on `AvgRT`, which has higher variance, yielded the same error. I then observed that removing `SessionType` from the `within` parameter yielded the following error:

```
> x <- anova_test(
+            data = pdf,
+            dv = AvgRT,
           within = c(Group)
+            wid = Subject,
+            within = c(Group)
+ )
Error in `spread()`:
! Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination
  of keys.
ℹ Keys are shared for 80 rows
• 1, 2
• 3, 4
• 5, 6
• 7, 8
• 9, 10
• 11, 12
• 13, 14
• 15, 16
• 17, 18
• 19, 20
• 21, 22
• 23, 24
• 25, 26
• 27, 28
• 29, 30
• 31, 32
• 33, 34
• 35, 36
• 37, 38
• 39, 40
• 41, 42
• 43, 44
• 45, 46
• 47, 48
• 49, 50
• 51, 52
• 53, 54
• 55, 56
• 57, 58
• 59, 60
• 61, 62
• 63, 64
• 65, 66
• 67, 68
• 69, 70
• 71, 72
• 73, 74
• 75, 76
• 77, 78
• 79, 80
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

What is going on? Why can't I perform this ANOVA test?